# vim html version of text document black on white

Tags: colorscheme, filetype-html

I'm trying to figure out a good workflow for printing source code and studying it.

So far, the `TOhtml` function seems really useful for this purpose. I can create an `html` file with ease, open it in a browser and get a source code listing with extremely legible line numbers.

My only complaint is that the resulting HTML file tries to mimic my white text on a dark background.

For instance, `foo.txt`

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

Which looks like this in my terminal

```
   1 Line 1
   2 Line 2
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
foo.txt
```

produces the following output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>~/tmp/foo.txt.html</title>
<meta name="Generator" content="Vim/8.1">
<meta name="plugin-version" content="vim8.1_v1">
<meta name="syntax" content="none">
<meta name="settings" content="number_lines,use_css,no_foldcolumn,expand_tabs,line_ids,prevent_copy=">
<meta name="colorscheme" content="least">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
pre { font-family: monospace; color: #ffffff; background-color: #000000; }
body { font-family: monospace; color: #ffffff; background-color: #000000; }
* { font-size: 1em; }
.LineNr { color: #008080; font-weight: bold; }
-->
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--

/* function to open any folds containing a jumped-to line before jumping to it */
function JumpToLine()
{
  var lineNum;
  lineNum = window.location.hash;
  lineNum = lineNum.substr(1); /* strip off '#' */

  if (lineNum.indexOf('L') == -1) {
    lineNum = 'L'+lineNum;
  }
  var lineElem = document.getElementById(lineNum);
  /* Always jump to new location even if the line was hidden inside a fold, or
   * we corrected the raw number to a line ID.
   */
  if (lineElem) {
    lineElem.scrollIntoView(true);
  }
  return true;
}
if ('onhashchange' in window) {
  window.onhashchange = JumpToLine;
}

-->
</script>
</head>
<body onload='JumpToLine();'>
<pre id='vimCodeElement'>
<span id="L1" class="LineNr">1 </span>Line 1
<span id="L2" class="LineNr">2 </span>Line 2
</pre>
</body>
</html>
<!-- vim: set foldmethod=manual : -->
```

I've tried disabling CSS via

`let g:html_use_css = 0`

but the resulting html file still mimics the colorscheme of my current vim configuration.

It seems like there should be a dedicated way to say "export this code as HTML in a way that will look nice when printed or viewed in a browser instead of mimicking what I see in my terminal".

I have found a 30% solution. Just call `sed` on the html that vim generates with css generation disabled. It will do in a pinch but seems less than ideal.

It is possible to manually adjust the colors with `sed`. This intentionally ugly command line avoids differences between BSD and GNU sed.

```
< foo.txt.html sed \
's/bgcolor="#......"/bgcolor="#ffffff"/;s/text="#......"/text="#000000"/' \
> /tmp/a.html ; \
cp /tmp/a.html foo.txt.html
```

Comment: have you tried to use a dedicated colorscheme that looks good in the browser before running `:TOhtml`? You may also raise a ticket here: https://bitbucket.org/fritzophrenic/vim-tohtml/

Answer (score 1):

In terminal Vim, the background for the HTML is derived from the option `background`. If it is set to `dark`, the HTML background is black. If `light` the HTML background is white. The colors are fixed. Changing the Vim colorscheme does *not* change the colors used in HTML.

In GVim the colors in the HTML match the colorscheme. If you use the colorscheme "default", you get a white background.

---

Another way would be to post-process the generated HTML and remove the internal CSS and replace it with a link to a external CSS file. You could then prepare a external CSS that fits your needs.

I don't know if this fits with your planed workflow. Anyway here is a quick-hack example:

```
let DEFAULT_CSS="My-default-css-file.css"

function! MyToHtml(bang, css)
    let myCss=g:DEFAULT_CSS
    if !empty(a:css)
        let myCss = a:css
    endif

    " Create HTML
    TOhtml

    " if bang is given, write a css file. Name derived from html file
    " but with extension 'css'
    if !empty(a:bang)
        let cssFilename = substitute(expand("%"), '\.html$', '.css', '')
        execute '/^<style type="text\/css">/+2;/^<\/style>/-2 write! ' . cssFilename
        call cursor(1, 1)
    endif

    " delete the inline css code and replace it with a stylesheet link
    execute '/^<style type="text\/css">/;/^<\/style>/d'
    put! ='<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"' . myCss . '\">'

endfunc


" Usage:
" MyToHtml[!] [css-file]
" If bang (!) is given, write css-file from css found in html
" If css-file is given use this as css-file
" If css-file is NOT given use css-file set in g:DEFAULT_CSS
command! -bang -nargs=? MyToHtml call MyToHtml(<q-bang>, <q-args>)
```

Comment: I think there is an empty function, to avoid comparing to the empty string.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, `empty()` works. Updated.